# Extjs reading complex JSON data into store

Tags: json, extjs

I have Json data something like this:

```
{

"Data":

    {
    "Columns":
    [
        {
            "Name":"Name",
            "Format":"string"
        },
        {
            "Name":"Age",
            "Format":"N2"
        }
    ],
    "Rows":
    [
        {"ExtensionData":{},"Cells":["Vikas", 23],"Emails":[{"ExtensionData": }, Email": vikas@something.com", "CellOrdinal":0}]},
        {"ExtensionData":{},"Cells":["Vikram", 27],"Emails":[{"ExtensionData":{},"Email":"vikram@something.com","CellOrdinal":0}]},     
    ]
    }
    "Grid Name":"Users"
    }
}
}
```

I need to bind this to my grid.

The "Columns" tag contains grid column names. "Rows" contain records of the grid. Also there are some data like Name of the grid which is fetched from the database. It's a slightly complicated structure.

How to get this data into a store? How should my model be?

Comment: Sorry ...could not format Json data properly!!!

Comment: I just want to mention that you also have a code button {} to format ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Atlast after lot of trial and error got the model ready...

```
Ext.define('Data', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
            { type: 'string', name: 'Grid Name' }
        ],
    hasMany: [{ model: 'Column', name: 'Columns' },
              { model: 'Row', name: 'Rows' }]
});

Ext.define("Column", {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
            { type: 'string', name: 'Name' },
            { type: 'string', name: 'Format' }
        ],
    belongsTo: 'Data'
});

Ext.define("Row", {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
            { type: 'string', name: 'Cells' },
            { type: 'string', name: 'Emails' }
        ],
    belongsTo: 'Data'
});
```